# rxjava2: receive same event many times

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a DownloadTransformer to down files. I am sure that I just emit one event when I finish download a file.

```
@Override
public ObservableSource<DownloadResponse<File>> apply(Observable<ProgressResult<Response>> upstream) {
    return upstream
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .filter(new Predicate<ProgressResult<Response>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(ProgressResult<Response> progressResult) {
                    return progressResult.getType() == OVER;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<ProgressResult<Response>, Observable<DownloadResponse<File>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<DownloadResponse<File>> apply(final ProgressResult<Response> progressResult) {
                    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<DownloadResponse<File>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<DownloadResponse<File>> e) {
                            DownloadResponse<File> result;
                            try {
                                ...
                                result.setStatus(OVER);
                                e.onNext(result);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                result.setStatus(FAIL);
                                e.onError();
                            } finally {
                                ...
                                e.onComplete();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

I download 3-4 files at the same time.
But when I finish download one of them, I often receive same event

```
MyRequestObservable
        .compose(new DownloadTransformer())
        .map(new Function<DownloadResponse<File>, NullObject>() {
            @Override
            public NullObject apply(DownloadResponse<File> fileDownloadResponse) {
                DownloadResponse.NetStatus status = fileDownloadResponse.getStatus();
                if (status != DownloadResponse.NetStatus.OVER) {
                    return NullObject.NULL_OBJECT;
                }
                //File file = fileDownloadResponse.getResponse();
                File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
                info.setFile(imageFile);
                //multi same events here...
                Log.d(TAG, "fileDownloadResponse: " + fileDownloadResponse);
                ...
                return NullObject.NULL_OBJECT;
            }
        })
        .safeSubscribe(new BaseObserver<NullObject>(mObservers));
```

log prints many same object fileDownloadResponse. Why the apply function called so many times?

I just want receive one event when I finish download a file, How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by receiving the same event?
do you make 3 observable for each file or one observable for all of them?

Comment: @seyedJafari I make 3 observable for each file.

Comment: and what do you mean by the same event?

Comment: @seyedJafari `Log.d(TAG, "fileDownloadResponse: " + fileDownloadResponse)` print same fileDownloadResponse object many times here.

Answer (score 0):

In case the events you are receiving identical events, you can use `.take(1)` or if using `Single` you can use `.firstOrError()` at the end of stream to close the stream when you have received the first event

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: I can add a filter then use `take(1)`, but why the log(the apply function) called so many times?